# Best approach for a scheduled update use case - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have an specific requirement to be implemented, and any thoughts on thet would be welcome

### The requirement

A given `Appointment` model has the following structure:

```
Appointment {
  status, # 'scheduled' or 'done'
  happens_at # Datetime
}
```

The `status` attribute that must be changed from `scheduled` to `done` at the time given by the attribute `happens_at`

### Possible solutions

#### Scheduling a Job

Using rails Active Job framework, as soon as the tuple is created, we can simply call a Job that will be responsible for setting the status as `'done'`

```rb
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def after_create
    RefreshAppointmentStatusJob.set(wait_until: created_appointment[:happens_at])
      .perform_later(created_appointment[:id])
  end
end
```

**apparent PROS**:

- Easy to implement on creation

**apparent CONS**:

- Need to handle job rescheduling if `Appointment.happens_at` is updated
- What happens if my queue gets corrupted? How to make sure any "lost" scheduling would be rescheduled?

#### Using cron job running every minute

Then there is this other possible solution, which is basically a cro job running every minute with an implementation like

```
class RefreshStatusService < ApplicationService
  def call
    Appointment.where('happens_at <= ?',  date).update_all(status: 'done')
  end
end
```

**apparent PROS**:

- Decouples this feature from Appointment creation/update/delete
- Any problem regarding the queue/cron execution should not interfeer on database consistance after it is fixed (I mean, as soon as the query is run, any outdated status is going to be corretly updated)

**apparent CONS**:

- Seems "dumb" to run this routine literally every minute, while probably most of thos runs are not updating anything
- Every update will not actually happen on the correct `happens_at`, if it considers the seconds. It means we can have at most ~60 seconds of outdated data, which might be acceptable or not, deppending on the application

### Best approach?

I've already implemented both solutions to similar problems, but every time I have to do it again I keep wondering which is the prefered solution. Any thoughts or opinions on thet would be very nice!

Note: I've used Ruby on Rails as example because it has built-in support for queues, but the problem itself would be faced on any other web framework

Comment: Sorry but this is not a an on-topic question - its not a bad question but Stackoverflow isn't the place for it. This is a Q&A site for practical programming questions that can be authoritively answered and any answer here is largely a matter of opinion. You might want to try other forums that are geared towards discussions instead like https://www.reddit.com/r/rubyonrails/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

I have used a third approach... based on the notion that, although `status` needs to be `done` after the `happens_at` date has passed, it really doesn't have to change at that moment, but it must be correctly set the next time anyone queries the object. So use an `after_initialize` callback, which will update the value of `status` whenever the object is fetched from the db, if the `happens_at` is in the past.

```rb
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize :set_status

  def set_status
    update(status: 'done') if happens_at.past?
  end
end
```

Comment: And what happens when you fetch 50 or 100 records to display on an index route?

Comment: @max each approach has pros and cons. You make your design decisions based on your app. I'm not saying that this is the way to go, just that I have done it this way with good results in my own situation.

Comment: In my humble opinion a read query unexpectedly creating N+1 update queries is a pretty big WTF moment. If you did this I (which I really would not recommend) use `after_find` so that the callback is not run when initializing new records which will unexpectly cause it to save. Welcome to callback hell.

Comment: @max I benchmarked the penalty on my MacBook air. For 100 records the N+1 adds 190mS. If this presents a problem in the target app, a different approach would be advised.

Comment: @LesNightingill interesting approach. I think a consireable disadvantage is having an inconsistent database, since this status consistency will be of full responsibility of the application layer. What I would be woried about is for any solution that might connect dirrectly to that database (like an ETL, backup manager, direct quering for business or debugging purposes, etc).
But anyway, I seems to have some advantages when it comes to simplicity
Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

and here's yet another approach! Rename the status field to, say, `raw_status` and then add a `status` method:

```rb
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  def status
    return 'done' if happens_at.past?
    raw_status
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice, this would fix the performance issue of database writes, but the concept of `done` status would belong to the application layer, which also brings (in my opinion) the same disadvantages.

Maybe a compound solution of this + a long interval job (instead of every minute, every 24h? before database backup?) would actually update `raw_status` could be scalable and also guaranteed consistency for most of the records.